# Check if file that match regexp is in directory

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if in directory there is a file that match particular expression. My filename consist of identifier and additional single character letter.

- Identifier **is** case insensitive
- Additional symbol **is not** case insensitive

Moreover they can be separated with some symbols like `_`, `-` or not.

For example: For given identifier `AC1C` and symbol `A` I want to check if there is a file named:

- `ac1cA.txt`
- `ac1c-A.txt`
- `ac1c_A.txt`
- `AC1CA.txt`
- `AC1C-A.txt`
- `AC1C_A.txt`

but not:

- `ac1c-a.txt`

I would rather check it with some kind of regexp than with checking six conditions separately. I'm using python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to check files that match   in your directory

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """
...     ac1cA.txt
...     ac1c-A.txt
...     ac1c_A.txt
...     AC1CA.txt
...     AC1C-A.txt
...     AC1C_A.txt
... """
>>> re.findall(r'(?:ac1c|AC1C)(?:-|_)?A\.txt', s)
['ac1cA.txt', 'ac1c-A.txt', 'ac1c_A.txt', 'AC1CA.txt', 'AC1C-A.txt', 'AC1C_A.txt']
```

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't work. This regexp match also `ac1ca.txt` which I wanted to exclude.

Comment: @user31027 fixed that

Comment: Thanks a lot. I adapted into my case, and it even works, but I'm not sure if it truly pythonic. Probably it is much simpler than I think:`file = [i for i in os.listdir(path) if re.search(r'(?:{}|{})(?:-|_)?{}\.txt'.format(id.lower(), id.upper(), char),i) ][0]`

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code

```
import re
string_sample = '''ac1cA.txt
ac1c-A.txt
ac1c_A.txt
AC1CA.txt
AC1C-A.txt
AC1C_A.txt'''

pattern = '[Aa][Cc][0-9][cC][-_]?A\.txt'
print re.findall(pattern, string_sample)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option, if your files are in `files_dir`:

```
import os
import re
import glob

def fmatch(id, symb, filenames):
    """ Determine if a file containing ID and symb exists in filenames."""
    patt = '{}|{}[-_]?{}'.format(id.upper(), id.lower(), symb)
    return any((re.match(patt, os.path.basename(filename)) for filename in filenames))

files_dir = 'testdir'
# List of .txt files in files_dir
filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(files_dir,'*.txt'))

id, symb = 'ac1c', 'A'

print fmatch(id, symb, filenames)
```